# Python Error: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to Python and I've searched for answers to this error, but I'm not experienced enough to see exactly where I'm going wrong - its probably something really basic.
I'm working on a project to identify authors based on the words they use in their texts. I add the words to a dictionary for each author, with the word as the key, and the value is the number of times the word occurs in the texts of that author. I also create a vocabulary of all the word of all authors and use these to calculate probabilities. This works fine, initially.
My problem comes when I add in k-fold cross validation, which I'm using as my corpus isn't particularly large.  I iterate through a list of the authors names, which matches the name I've assigned to their empty dictionary. Once I've extracted the files I want, I want to add the cleaned/parsed text to the dictionary, but I get the above error, which refers to the line *author[word]= 1* in my dictionary fn, which I call in the second last line of code below .  From my reading of other answers, its to do with str being immutable, but I just can't see how to apply the answers to my problem.  your help is much appreciated!
Ps I know there are libraries etc that can do all this work, but the whole idea of the project is to build my own model, and compare it with other models.

```
path = "C:\\......\The Letters\\"

#create an empty vocab set
vocab = set()
stop = stopwords.words('english')

snowball = SnowballStemmer('english')

#create empty dictionary for each author
AuthorA = {}
AuthorB = {}
AuthorC = {}

authorList = ["AuthorA","AuthorB","Authorc"]

#function to preprocess the words.  Opens & reads file, removes non alphabet
#characters, converts to lowercase, and tokenizes
def cleanText(path,author,eachfile):    
    f= open(path+author+"\\"+eachfile, "r")        
    contents = f.read()   
    strip = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]',' ',contents) 
    lowerCase = strip.lower()    
    allwords = lowerCase.split()    
    return allwords

#function to add words to the vocabulary set
def createVocab(allwords):    
    for word in allwords:
        if len(word)>= 4:
            vocab.update(allwords)
    return

#function to add words to author dictionary and count occurrences of each word    
def dictionary(allwords, author):
    for word in allwords:
        if len(word)>= 4:
            if word in author:
                author[word]= author[word]+1
            else:
                author[word]= 1 
    return


def main():
    global authorList
    global path
    global vocab
    global AuthorA
    global AuthorB
    global AuthorC

    for author in authorList:
#filename and path
        listing = os.listdir(path+author)

#specify parameters for k fold validation
        #split into 10 folds and take a file form each fold
        #repeat for until the entire directory has been split
        folds = 10
        subset_size = len(path+author)/folds
        for i in range(folds):
            #use these files to train the model
            current_train = listing[:i*subset_size:]+listing[(i+1)*subset_size:]
            #use these files to test the model
            current_test = listing[i*subset_size:][:subset_size]

    #iterate through the files selected by current_train variable 
                for eachfile in current_train:
    #call function to parse text         
                    allwords = cleanText(path,author,eachfile)                
    #call fn to add words to dictionary
                    dictionary(allwords, author)                
    #call fn to add words to vocab
                    createVocab(allwords)
```

Comment: on which line are you getting the error?

Comment: Please, get familiar with [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Question, as stated now, is far too broad for SO standards. Also, take care about indentation. In Python indentation is part of syntax, and in your code it looks suspicious.

Comment: the error is when i call the dictionary function on the 2nd last line, and refers to else: author[word]=1.  I think D.Cam has answered, i just need to figure out collections now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing into your dictionary function a string for the variable author.  The top for loop, `for author in authorList:` is iterating over a list of strings, not a dict collection. `authorList = ["AuthorA","AuthorB","Authorc"]`

You want to pass in a dict collection to your function. Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks, I'll give that a go.  I just need to figure out how to use a dict collection!

Comment: You have pretty much the right usage.  Instead of using a list, you could always use a dict.  `authors = {"AuthorA": AuthorA, "AuthorB":AuthorB, "AuthorC":AuthorC}` and then you can iterate over them using `for author, author_dict in authors.iteritems()`

Comment: yes, that's pretty much what I eventually figured out.  I created a nested dictionary so that i can store the words for each author, and I'm iterating over the keys.  Thanks for your help!